# Azure Virtual machine remote destop issue

Tags: azure

I have created one virtual machine on azure windows 2012 datacenter.

I am not able to take remote while clicking on RDP file it gives error

1. Remote access to server not enable
2. Remote computer is turned off
3. Remote computer is not available on the network

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable RDP inbound in 2 places: 
1) the Azure Network Security Group (assuming you created the VM as an Azure Resource Manager VM instead of a "classic" VM), and 
2) the firewall on the VM itself.